# General solution of the equation $\sin^4(x)= 1 +\tan^8(y)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the general solution of the equation

$$\sin^4(x)= 1 +\tan^8(y)$$

So I tried solving this by taking a look at the extreme values

LHS is always less than or equal to  $1$, i.e,

$$\sin^4(x)\leq1$$

RHS is always greater than or equal to $1$, i.e,

$$1+\tan^8(y)\geq1$$

$$\implies \tan^8(y) = 0$$ and $$\sin^4(x) =  1$$

This gives the 1st solution to be $$y = m\pi$$ for the tan equation

For the sin equation, I can write, taking roots and as RHS will always be +ve as LHS will have $\sin^2(x)$ in it,

$$\sin^2(x) = 1 = sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

This gives the general solution $$x = n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But the 2nd solution is given as only $$x = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Why is the negative missing??

Also, in my book's theory, it states that if

> $\sin^2(x)=\sin^2(A) \implies x = n\pi \pm A$
>
> $|\sin(x)|=1 \implies x = n\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$

Shouldn't I get the negative sign also if I use the 1st part of the theory, putting A = $\frac{\pi}{2}$??

Comment: @user yes was a mistake while typing it out

Comment: If $n \in \Bbb Z$, then the negative solutions are included in the statement $x=n\pi + \frac{\pi}2$, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression 
$$
x=n\pi+\frac\pi2
$$
is correct.

The expression
$$
x=n\pi\pm\frac\pi2
$$
lists all solutions twice for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.